# ASP.Net URL Rewrite module Javascript CSS images not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I wanted to do URL rewrite with Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule in ASP.Net here is my following configuration in web.config

```
>  <configSections>
>     <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler,
> Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />   </configSections>
```

in system.web

```
 <httpModules>
      <add type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" name="UrlRewriter" />
    </httpModules>
```

I want follwoing type of url

> site.com/home 
>   site.com/contact 
>   site.com/info
>   site.com/page/innerpage
>   site.com/in/info

for this I have write following rules respectively

```
<system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Home$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="\.aspx$"  />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^contact$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="contact.aspx" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL3" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="info.aspx?keyword={R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite to page.aspx">
          <match url="^pages/([^/]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="page.aspx?page={R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite to info.aspx">
          <match url="([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="info.aspx?keyword2={R:1}&amp;keyword={R:2}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <rewriter>

  </rewriter>
```

all works fine but if use last rule I have used to get and CSS / javascript stops working all I tried many solutions to resolve css/javascript/image rule imply but not worked.

> site.com/in/info

```
 <rule name="Rewrite to info.aspx">
              <match url="([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="info.aspx?keyword2={R:1}&amp;keyword={R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)$" />`

And I usually add a role to rewrite every page so that you don't need .aspx in the url. So you can write www.domain.com/home instead of www.domain.com/home.aspx, www.domain.com/subpage/contact instead of www.domain.com/subpage/contact.aspx etc.

```
<rule name="no_aspx" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I did changes but its same no change